# Why iterate loop on instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess never executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

r[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddKvr.jpg) is an instance of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` and the following r[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddKvr.jpg) iterate loop was skipped and was not executed (without error):

```
req_get.each do |r|
  if r[0].to_s.include?(model)
    sub_hash = ''
    r[1].each do |r1|
       if sub_hash.present?
         sub_hash += '&' + r[0].to_s + '[' + r1[0].to_s  + ']=' + r1[1].to_s
       else
         sub_hash = r[0].to_s + '[' + r1[0].to_s  + ']=' + r1[1].to_s
       end
    end
  end
end
```

Here req_get is value of request.GET. The reg_get.each loop is working fine.

We filled never-wrong code within the r[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddKvr.jpg) do loop and the result is the same (no execution). What's the right way to iterate this `HashWithIndifferentAccess` object? This is rails 3.2 app. Also tried r[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddKvr.jpg).map do |k, v| and the problem is the same.

reg_get (request.GET) contain the params[:model] which is passed into controller. The code above was parsing through the reg_get.

[image]

Comment: What is `sub_hash`, and where is it defined?

Comment: sub_hash is defined as sub_hash='' before the loop.

Comment: How do you know the block is not executed?

Comment: nitpick change `sub_hash = ''` to `sub_hash ||= ''` you are always re-assigning `sub_hash`, secondly, you would not have access to `sub_hash` outside the `.each` loop, so if you want to use it subsequently, you need to define it before the loop itself

Comment: In debug. sub_hash was nil.

Comment: bjhaid, the r[1] loop is for model only and will be executed only once. The rest is skipped.

Comment: @user938363 not sure I understand what you are saying

Comment: `r1` is the instance of the class, but you redefine it in the loop? So, each `reg_get` contains `r's`, that in turn contain various things, among which each `r[1]`, which becomes `r1`, is an instance of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`?

Comment: bjhaid, You are right. The sub_bash gets re-assigned. The problem is caused by the reassign of the sub_bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each do |key, value|` instead of `|r1|`

and replace `r[0]` with `k` and `r[1]` with `v`

Comment: The problem is the same.